# I can't access a site that I just created on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm getting a super weird issue whereby I just created a site on aws (s3, cf, route53) and now I'm getting `This site can't be reached issue`

it's weird for the following reasons:

- I can access it on my phone
- my friends can access it
- I could initially access it but now cant

my internet connection is fine (hence posting on here) and accessing other sites

I've cleared my browser cache (but the issue occurs in firefox too??). I've tried incognito too

I restarted my laptop and it then briefly worked but after the 3rd refresh it died

I know this is super weird so not expecting it to be solved really but just wondering if anyone else has experienced this after launching a site and how I can fix it? really don't get why it's happening on my computer and noone elses (makes it hard to debug)

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidation of the cache, it’s possible a specific cache is broken.

Comment: as in the cloudfront cache?

Comment: Yes, try invalidating the whole thing

Comment: I have and nothing :(

Comment: I can view my site fine via cloudfront just not on the mapped name. Route 53 says it's healthy too..

Comment: And the distribution config has the additional hostname there?

Comment: why would that effect just my machine tho?

Comment: Well if it’s not there it shouldn’t be accessible by anyone